# What manga is Ken Akamatsu currently working on?

Tags: ken-akamatsu

Is Ken Akamatsu currently working starting a new series or planning to release a new one this year?

I understand that *Negima* ended some time ago. A mangaka's gotta eat, after all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about time-limited "news" events. The accepted answer is already out of date since we know the new manga is UQ Holder. When UQ Holder concludes, the whole question will become irrelevant because it won't be what Akamatsu is "currently" working on anymore, and the possible edit "What was Ken Akamatsu working on in late 2013?" is easily answered with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Update- Ken Akamatsu's new manga is named [UQ Holder.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UQ_Holder!)

Set in the same universe of his previous work Negima! Magister Negi Magi, but over 70 years later, it follows the adventures of a young boy who is transformed into a vampire and joins a secret society composed of immortal beings.

Comment: I found this out before I accessed this message. I picked it up at the bookstore. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 8):

He *is* working on a new manga series (name unknown) which is apparently scheduled to begin some time this summer. It was originally set to be released in spring. As noted in the article linked below, he has stated that this will be his last series; he plans to retire after it.

Source: [Nikkei](http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXBZO52528800X00C13A3HR0A00/?df=2)
Translation: [OK](http://otakukokka.com/2013/03/10/new-manga-series-from-ken-akamatsu-start-this-summer/)